# Display struct variable with printf("\n")

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, struct, printf

I tried implemented matrix struct in C, ( generate and show that ). I don't have a trouble with generate but i discovered something I didn't understand. When i uncomment printf("\n") i don't get variable from matrix but whith commented printf("\n") everything working correct. It's not a big problem but I'm curious why this happen. It's looks like printf has destructed my structure.

```
void show_matrix(struct matrix matrix1){
     for(int i =0; i < matrix1.number_of_row; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j <matrix1.number_of_columns; j++){
            printf("%d " , matrix1.variable[i * matrix1.number_of_columns + j]);
           }
           // printf("\n");
     } 
}
```

Here is my main :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "matrix_operations.h"
int main(){

   int columns;
   int rows;
   printf("Enter the number of columns \n");
   scanf("%d",&columns);
   printf("Enter the number of rows \n");
   scanf("%d", &rows);
   struct matrix matrix1;
   matrix1  = generate_matrix(columns,rows);
   show_matrix(matrix1);
   return 0;
}
```

Here is my file matrix_operations.h :

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

struct matrix generate_matrix(int columns, int rows){
int value;
struct matrix matrix1;
matrix1.number_of_columns = columns;
matrix1.number_of_row = rows;
int values[rows * columns];
matrix1.variable = values;
for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++){
     for(int j =0 ; j <columns ; j++){
          value = random() %2;
          matrix1.variable[i * columns +j] = value;
          /* Uncomment to see generated matrix 
          printf("%d ", matrix1.values[ i * columns +j]);
          */
          }
   /* Uncomment to see generated matrix 
   printf("\n");
    */
   }
 return matrix1;
 }
 void show_matrix(struct matrix matrix1){
      for(int i =0; i < matrix1.number_of_row; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j <matrix1.number_of_columns; j++){
             printf("%d " , matrix1.variable[i * matrix1.number_of_columns + j]);
           }
      /* Uncomment to not working correctly
      printf("\n");
      */
      } 
}
```

Here is my struct in file matrix.h :

```
struct matrix{
   int number_of_columns;
   int number_of_row;
   int *variable;
};
```

Sample input :

```
4
4
```

Sample output with commented printf (16 random numbers 0 or 1):

```
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

Sample output with uncommented printf

```
1 0 1 1 
-2051332800 32571 0 0 
0 0 -2053095405 32571 
-2051684704 32571 10 0
```

Comment: Stdout is "buffered". Certain events are required to flush it - like printing a new line.

Comment: But the question is the other way round: *doesn't* work when the newline is output.

Comment: ...this kind of strangeness can be a symptom of undefined behaviour *somewhere else* in the code.

Comment: ```fflush(stdout);``` ensures that all data is sent to output.

Comment: @Cebul Since your question is missing most of the code, would you mind to include the output before you comment the `printf("\n");` and after you comment such line?

Comment: Oh, I totally read it backwards. I don't see how _adding_ the `printf` can cause a problem. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @MatheusRossiSaciotto true, but OP seems to want a simple line break between each row of the matrix.

Comment: `public` and code tagged C??  Post a [mcve].

Comment: Okay I etited my question.  I didn't create public void in orginal code, It's my mistake to add this in question.

Comment: Please provide sampel input, the output in both versions for that input and explain in prose how the expectation is matched in one but not the other. Only with that, shown code is really a [mre].

Comment: Indeed the `printf` statement is destroying your matrix, since you didn’t allocate any persistent memory for its values. The `generate_matrix` function has the data in local variables, which may be destroyed as soon as that function exits. Probably your `printf` uses some of the memory used by that function, thereby overwriting the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `generate_matrix` returns a `struct matrix` with a `variable` field that points at a local variable (`values`) of the function.  This goes out of scope when the function returns, leaving you with a dangling pointer, and when you later dereference it, you get undefined behavior.

You need to ensure that this pointer points at something with sufficient lifetime to not become dangling.  One way to do that would be to use `malloc` in the `generate_matrix` function rather than using a local variable:

```
int *values = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(int));
```

This will allocate memory that lasts until you explicitly free it.  Now you have the issue that you need to figure out when to free it (when you no longer need it), or you'll have a memory leak.